# Create multi-hop SSH tunnel with different user on end machine

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel

I have tried creating a multi-hop SSH tunnel using a command like this:

```
ssh -L 2222:username@host2:22 host1 -N
```

However, when I try to use the SSH tunnel like this

```
ssh -p 2222 localhost
```

I get this error where I run the second command

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

and this error where I run the first command

```
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> ssh -L 2222:username@host2:22 host1 -N
> ```

You don't specify the user here. You specify the user only in the connection, therefore

```
ssh -L 2222:host2:22 host1_username@host1 -N
```

or

```
ssh -p 2222 username@localhost
```

depends on where the `username` belongs.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a lot of different things, but I didn't even consider the `username@localhost` idea.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question, as the user@host1 is different than the user@host2.

Comment: @Excalibur it does. In the question, there is nothing about different users. But I added different users to show the usernames can be different.

Comment: @Excalibur: to explain: the question shows that he can connect to host1 using no name (so using its current name, maybe root, or let's say "localuser"), but then he needed (in his mind) to use a different name, `username`, on `host2`. The 1st ssh creates (-L) a tunnel "toward" host2 port 22(=sshd), but it **doesn't access** that endpoint (host2:port 22) at this stage. Once it is set in place, the 2nd ssh (`ssh -p 2222 username@localhost`) use the setup tunnel to arrive to `host2`'s sshd, and at this point only does the incoming ssh need to specify the `username@` he needs to connect to.